# Vector out of range

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, vector, c++-cli

I am trying to draw a bounding box around contours using OpenCV. This is a real time application where all the images are grabbed from a camera real time, and Following is the important part of the code

**RTMotionDetector.h**

```
vector<vector<Point>> *contours;
    vector<vector<Point>> *contoursPoly;
```

**RTMotionDetector.cpp**

```
RTMotionDetector::RTMotionDetector(void)
{
    current = new Mat();
    currentGrey = new Mat();
    canny = new Mat();
    next = new Mat();
    absolute = new Mat();

    cam1 = new VideoCapture();
    cam2 = new VideoCapture();

    contours = new vector<vector<Point>>();
    contoursPoly = new vector<vector<Point>>();
    boundRect = new vector<Rect>();

}

double RTMotionDetector::getMSE(Mat I1, Mat I2)
{
    Mat s1;

    //Find difference
    cv::absdiff(I1, I2, s1);       // |I1 - I2|
    imshow("Difference",s1);

    //Do canny to get edges
    cv::Canny(s1,*canny,30,30,3);
    imshow("Canny",*canny);

    //Find contours
    findContours(*canny,*contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    //System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(""+contours->size());

    //Draw contours
    drawContours(*current,*contours,-1,Scalar(0,0,255),2);
    for(int i=0;i<contours->size();i++)
    {
        cv::approxPolyDP(Mat((*contours)[i]),(*contoursPoly)[i],3,true);
        //boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contoursPoly[i]);
    }
}
```

As soon as the following part gets executed, I am getting an error

```
cv::approxPolyDP(Mat((*contours)[i]),(*contoursPoly)[i],3,true);
```

Here is the error I am getting.

[image]

If I comment out that piece of code, then no issues. I know this is `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` issue but I really can't find a fix. May be because I am new to Windows Programming.

It is very important that `contours` stay as a pointer instead of local variable, because local variable slowed the program in an unbelievable way.

Comment: I've never seen so many `new`s in one place. Please use smart pointers **if you absolutely must have pointers**.

Comment: Press Retry, debug the application. Chances are you're not filling your vector with anything.

Comment: @TheForestAndtheTrees: I did. Nothing changed :(

Comment: Absolutely follow @chris's advice. Otherwise you are going to get into lots of trouble, this time and in the future. This is not C#, you don't need to `new` everything.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: The problem is this is C++/CLI. It won't work without pointers if the variables are defined in header

Comment: C++/CLI is a different language from C++. C++/CLI is a .NET language, and C++ is not. I will fix your tags.

Comment: What you say about headers and pointers, though, sounds very strange to me. Anyway, I'm not going to try to remember all the weird C++/CLI syntax now.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: I also jumped to the same situation at the beginning. If I use without pointers, then the error "Mix types not allowed" is coming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find which access to which vector has gone beyond its bounds.

You loop til the size of contours,

```
for(int i=0;i<contours->size();i++)
```

but then access `(*contoursPoly)[i]`

I would hazard a guess that the contoursPoly has gone beyond its bounds, which you can check by breaking into the debugger as suggested.

Changing the loop to

```
for(int i=0;i<contours->size() && i<contoursPoly->size();i++)
```

might solve the immediate problem.

Comment: Yes, true. I used your technique until I find the complete fix. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
(*contoursPoly)[i]
```

you try to access something that doesn't exist.

What's more, the documentation says:

> C++: void approxPolyDP(InputArray curve, OutputArray approxCurve, double epsilon, bool closed)
>   ...
>   **approxCurve** - (...) The type should match the type of the input **curve** (...)

Here you have input - Mat and output - vector< Point >. Maybe that works too, IDK.